# Is there a way to reload a function but not the whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image that is streamed from Soundcloud `//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js`

```
var song = 0;

function artwork() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    SC.get("/users/user/favorites", function(track){
        $('#soundcloudimage').css('background-image', 'url(' + track[song].artwork_url.replace('large', 't500x500') + ')'); 
    });
});
```

And then I have another function which changes which track (`song`) to get the artwork from:

```
function changeSong() {
    song = song + 1;
}
```

And the html:

```
<div id="soundcloudimage"></div>
<button onclick="changeSong();">Next</button>
```

But currently it does nothing when I click on the button. I believe it needs to refresh the artwork function but I want it to do this without refreshing the whole page? How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at an AJAX tutorial with jQuery - you want to reload the **content**, not the function

Comment: @scrowler I believe that the ajax functionality is being handled by soundcloud SKD `SC.get()`. What the OP wants indeed is to call the function artwork again. Though i think he should re-write it but thats another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if you want to call the artwork function again:
function changeSong()
{
song = song + 1;
artwork();
}
```